# What's with this padding on the left side of my page?

Tags: default, margin, center, padding

I'm making a site from scratch, and haven't gotten far before getting stuck-
It's very simple code, and nowhere do I specify margins or padding, yet when I view the page in Chrome and Firefox, there's this margin on the left side keeping anything from existing for the first 25 or so pixels.  Something tells me this is normal/default, but is there any way I can completely center the page, surely it cannot be truly centered with this left:10px looking thing...

Here's the CSS:

```
.header {
height:100px;
width:100%;
top:100px;
z-index: 1;
position:fixed;
background-color:#767676;
top:0px;
```

}

html {

```
background-color:transparent;
color:#555555;
font-family: 'Roboto', 'Univers';
line-height: 1.0em;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#f8f8f8;
```

}

...And a screenshot showing exactly what I'm talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFDID.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a CSS reset of some sort to erase browser defaults. On my projects, I include `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` at the top of my CSS. This takes care of almost everything.

Comment: Looks like it had something to do with the divs, if I start from scratch, the text is perfectly on the left.  Thanks, I'll start that habit as well!